# Looping in Python 2.7 Tkinter to change Label

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I recently began learning how to use Python's(2.7) Tkinter, and i came across the Label widget. I want to be able to change what is being displayed by that widget(not write new text, but replace the previous text. This is what I tried:

```
number=0
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
var = StringVar()
number=number+1
label = Label( root, textvariable=var, relief=RAISED )
var.set(str(number))
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

When I run it it just displays "1". I understand that it isn't looping through the numbers, but doesn't .mainloop() keep looping through the code? How would i go about making this code work, and would this replace the previous line of text displayed, or would it write a new line of text below the one previously displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`root.mainloop()` is tkinter's own event handler.  It waits for and processes events from widgets, not user code block.  To periodically execute your own code block, you can use `root.after()`:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
var = StringVar()
Label(root, textvariable=var, relief=RAISED).pack()

def update_number(value):
    var.set(value)
    root.after(1000, update_number, value+1) # run again 1 second later

update_number(0) # initiate the update process
root.mainloop()
```